# Init Swift Class with empty object

Tags: swift

I'm very new to Swift and SwiftUI. I'm trying to init a class, which takes another object as a parameter. Here's the class.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
//
//
@Model final class AF_PenName {
    var dateCreated: Date
    var dateUpdated: Date
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var myBook: Book?
    
    init(dateCreated: Date, dateUpdated: Date, id: UUID, name: String, myBook: Book?) {
        self.dateCreated = .now
        self.dateUpdated = .now
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.myBook = myBook
    }    
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to init it.

```
 private func CreateFirstName()
    {
         let penName = AF_PenName(dateCreated: .now, dateUpdated: .now, id: UUID(), name: "Pen Name", myBook: Book)
        
        modelContext.insert(penName)        
    }
```

It's giving me the error at myBook: Book, which is because I'm not giving it an actual Book object, but at this stage in the code, there is no Book object, it hasn't been created yet, so I'm not sure how to init the AF_PenName object?

Comment: Pass `nil` and not `Book`

Answer (score 1):

Because the `init`'s `myBook` parameter accepts an optional, you can pass `nil` there. What should work for you is the following:

```
 private func CreateFirstName() {
     let penName = AF_PenName(dateCreated: .now, dateUpdated: .now, id: UUID(), name: "Pen Name", myBook: nil)
    
    modelContext.insert(penName)        
}
```

That being said, the way your `init` function is written could be cleaned up a bit. You pass many parameters, but you don't actually use them. Consider using the following:

```
init(id: UUID, name: String, myBook: Book?) {
    self.dateCreated = .now
    self.dateUpdated = .now
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.myBook = myBook
}
```

The values passed for `dateCreated` and `dateUpdated` are never used and those variables will always be set to `.now`, so there is no need to include them.

Edit: I want to back up vadian's approach of using default values to clean up a bit. Depending on how you initialize with that `init` function in the future, his approach is more flexible. Also, ditto the naming conventions. (Also, if you want to read some boring stuff about how Apple wants your code to look, [take a peek here](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).)

Answer (score 1):

There are two *edge cases* in your code.

- Regardless of the parameters `dateCreated` and `dateUpdated` in the `init` method both dates are always set to the current date. If this is intended omit the parameters, if not set `self.dateCreated` to `dateCreated` and `self.dateUpdated` to `dateUpdated`
- The value of the parameter `myBook` must be a `Book` instance (or `nil`) but not the type.

My suggestion is to add default values in the `init` method

```
@Model final class AF_PenName {
    var dateCreated: Date
    var dateUpdated: Date
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var myBook: Book?
    
    init(dateCreated: Date = .now, 
         dateUpdated: Date = .now, 
         id: UUID = UUID(), 
         name: String, 
         myBook: Book? = nil) {

           self.dateCreated = dateCreated
           self.dateUpdated = dateUpdated
           self.id = id
           self.name = name
           self.myBook = myBook
    }    
}
```

Then your `createFirstName` – please name functions with starting lowercase letter – can be reduced to

```
private func createFirstName() {
    let penName = AF_PenName(name: "Pen Name")        
    modelContext.insert(penName)        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem in this line is:

```
let penName = AF_PenName(dateCreated: .now, dateUpdated: .now, id: UUID(), name: "Pen Name", myBook: Book)
```

`myBook: Book` which passes the type. But you have to pass the object, and for that you need to initialize it like this:
`myBook: Book()` which is a default initializer for any new object.

Some people suggested cleaner code, that is nice, and some people suggested to pass nil, which kinda works, but understanding difference between declaring a type and initializing will help you in the future.

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't know that `Book` has an initializer with no parameters. The `Book` class/struct` details are not shown.

Comment: Even if it doesn't have an empty initializer, it should be created as convenience initializer instead to passing nil.

Comment: No there should not be an empty initializer since there are non optional properties involved. Where did you get the idea that init() is the default initializer?